# R: Extract data from string using POSIX regular expression

Tags: regex, r, string

How to extract only DATABASE_NAME from this string using POSIX-style regular expressions?

```
st <- "MICROSOFT_SQL_SERVER.DATABASE\INSTANCE.DATABASE_NAME."
```

First of all, this generates an error

```
Error: '\I' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "MICROSOFT_SQL_SERVER.DATABASE\I"
```

I was thinking something like

```
sub(".*\\.", st, "")
```

Comment: Instead you can indexOf second and third dots(.) and then , can substring it to get the DATABASE_NAME...

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that you have the second and third arguments the wrong way round in your Q. It is `sub(pattern, replacement, string)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that you need to escape the `\` in your string:

```
st <- "MICROSOFT_SQL_SERVER.DATABASE\\INSTANCE.DATABASE_NAME."
```

As for the main problem, this will return the bit you want from the string you gave:

```
> sub("\\.$", "", sub("[A-Za-z0-9\\._]*\\\\[A-Za-z]*\\.", "", st))
[1] "DATABASE_NAME"
```

But a simpler solution would be to split on the `\\.` and select the last chunk:

```
> strsplit(st, "\\.")[[1]][3]
[1] "DATABASE_NAME"
```

or slightly more automated

```
> sst <- strsplit(st, "\\.")[[1]]
> tail(sst, 1)
[1] "DATABASE_NAME"
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers provided some really good alternative ways of cracking the problem using `strsplit` or `str_split`.

However, if you *really* want to use a regex and `gsub`, this solution substitutes the first two occurrences of a (string followed by a period) with an empty string.

Note the use of the `?` modifier to tell the regex not to be greedy, as well as the `{2}` modifier to tell it to repeat the expression in brackets two times.

```
gsub("\\.", "", gsub("(.+?\\.){2}", "", st)) 
[1] "DATABASE_NAME"
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use `str_split` in package `stringr`.  The idea is to split st into strings at each period, and then to isolate the third string:

```
st <- "MICROSOFT_SQL_SERVER.DATABASE\\INSTANCE.DATABASE_NAME."

library(stringr)

str_split(st, "\\.")[[1]][3]

[1] "DATABASE_NAME"
```

Comment: +1 for the string splitting idea - was thinking along similar lines with a base R solution after battling with that regexp.